# Can Indian national with Canadian PR card get UK transit visa?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, legal, canadian-residents

We are nationals of India, with valid Canadian PR cards. As we have a 22-hour layover in London, with an onward flight to Canada, can we get a transit visa (48 hours) after landing at LHR (Terminal 4)?

Comment: You cannot get a visa after landing in the UK, full stop. They don't do that. Under certain conditions you will be allowed to enter _without_ a visa, but that's more or less the opposite of "get a transit visa" -- that is, _not needing one in the first place_.

Comment: You can get a transit visa BEFORE travelling (subject to conditions below) but not after landing.

Answer (score 1):

According to [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa) you are eligible for a transit visa if:

- you’ll be in transit to another country, with enough funds and the intention to travel on
- you can enter that country
- the only purpose of your visit to the UK is transit
- Leave the UK within 48h

Based on the information you have given you meet these requirements, with your Canadian PR cards you can enter Canada, you are within the 48h timeframe and you are only transitting.

**EDIT:**
After reading your question again based on Henning Makholms comment on you wanting to get the VISA after landing, that is not possible, at all.

Comment: That sounds like the conditions for landside transit **without** a visa, not for _getting_ a transit visa.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Check the linked source, it is clearly about the "transit visa" and when you need or don't need one.

Comment: Hmm, yes, on further check, those are the conditions you have quoted. But that is not helpful for the OP because he is asking whether he can apply for such a transit visa _after landing_, which he definitely cannot!